# Properly catching an unclosed string in ANTLR4

Tags: antlr4, string-literals

I have to define string literal in ANTLR4 and catch UNCLOSE_STRING exceptions.

Strings are surrounded by a pair of "" and have may have supported escapes:

`\b \f \r \n \t \’ \\`

The only way for `"` to appear inside a string is to be appended by a
`'` ('").

I have tried various ways to define a string literal but they were all catched by UNCLOSE_STRING:

```
program: global_variable_part function_declaration_part EOF;
<!-- Shenanigans of statements ...-->
fragment Character: ~( [\b\f\r\n\t"\\] | '\'') | Escape | '\'"';
fragment Escape: '\\' ( 'b' | 'f' | 'r' | 'n' | 't' | '\'' | '\\');
fragment IllegalEscape: '\\' ~( 'b' | 'f' | 'r' | 'n' | 't' | '\'' | '\\') ;

STR_LIT: '"' Character* '"' {
    content = str(self.text)
    self.text = content[1:-1]
};

UNCLOSE_STRING: '"' Character* ([\b\f\r\n\t\\] | EOF) {
    esc = ['\b', '\t', '\n', '\f', '\r', '\\']
    content = str(self.text)
    raise UncloseString(content)
};
```

For example
`"ab'"c\\n def"`  would match but only `Unclosed String: ab'"c\n def"`    was produced.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite close to the specification for Strings in Java.  Don't be afraid to "borrow" from other grammars.  I slight modification to the [Java Lexer rules](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/java9/Java9.g4) that (I think) matches your needs would be:

```
StringLiteral
    :   '"' StringCharacters? '"'
    ;
fragment
StringCharacters
    :   StringCharacter+
    ;
fragment
StringCharacter
    :   ~["\\\r\n]
    |   EscapeSequence
    ;

fragment
EscapeSequence
    :   '\\' [btnfr'\\]
    :   "\'""  // <-- the '" escape match
    ;
```

If you know of another language that's a closer match, you can look at how it was handled for looking for it's grammar here ([ANTLR4 Grammars](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4))